# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 - save and reload .selection in FBFriendPickerViewController

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

FBFriendPickerViewController seems pretty straightforward. However, it may not be designed for the scenario I want.

Essentially, I want to save a list of friends the user selects to disk. On subsequent app launches, I want to show the FBFriendPickerViewController with these "saved" friends as being already selected.

Since the .selection attribute is readonly, I'm not sure how I can load a new instance of FBFriendPickerViewController with a subset of friends already "selected".

Comment: the question is old but I'm still looking for the solution, any luck for this?

Comment: I'll be bringing this old iOS6 app from the dead - keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found out the solution.

I have an NSDictionary `dict` whose key is the facebook user id and the value is the name.
Roughly, this is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id key in dict) {
  NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:key];
  id<FBGraphUser> user = (id<FBGraphUser>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
  user.id = key;
  [user setName:name]; // This is not mandatory
  if (user) {
    NSLog(@"adding user: %@", user.name);
    [results addObject:user];
  }
}
// And finally set the selection property
friendPickerController.selection = results;
```

**UPDATE:** it seems like it doesn't work properly....you will see the friends correctly checked, but when you will go to parse the `.selection` when you finish the selection, you will get only the friends you checked in the UI, not the preloaded ones...

**UPDATE 2:** it seems to work fine if you fill up all the fields listed in the [FBGraphUser.h](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBGraphUser.h) header file