# FBFriendPickerViewController - initialize with previously selected friends checked

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm new to the friend picker. I'm trying to save selected friends to database, and show those friends as selected when reloading the friend picker. Can't seem to find anything so far.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. Basically the question is: Is there a way to modify the readonly "selection" property of a FBFriendPickerViewController?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257408/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-save-and-reload-selection-in-fbfriendpickerviewcontrolle

Comment: i know it's almost 2 years old now...but any success with this task?

Answer (score 0):

Object of the class "FBFriendPickerViewController" has an array named "selection" which contains list users selcted. Try using this to store selected FB ids in NSUserDefaults and fetch next time. May be like below.

```
NSMutableArray *arryOfFBIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) 
    [arryOfFBIds addObject:user.id];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject: arryOfFBIds forKey: @"SelectedFBIds"];
[defaults synchronize];

[arryOfFBIds release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already saving the selected friends in an array. The problem I am trying to solve is how to load the selected friends from the array into the friendpicker so that they appear checked when the picker is reopened. Any ideas? I am going crazy searching.